# Arduino + Módulo SIM900 + PHP + MySQL - Problema método POST

Tags: php, mysql, web-service, app, arduino

Boa tarde a todos!,

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto que consiste na comunicação de um módulo SIM900 com um aplicativo, e fazendo a interação dos dois estará um servidor WEB + Banco de Dados.

Os itens APP, Banco de Dados e página PHP já estão funcionando perfeitamente.

PROBLEMA: Estou tendo problema na comunicação do módulo SIM900 pelo método POST com a pagina que fará o "ADD" da informação no banco de dados MySQL.

Consegui realizar a adição das informações no Banco de Dados pelo método GET (via URL)

```
AT+SAPBR=1,1

AT+HTTPINIT

AT+HTTPPARA="URL","site/add.php?variável1=xx&Variavel2=xx&Variavel3=xx"

AT+HTTPACTION=0
```

**Porém** por motivos de segurança tenho que utilizar o método POST, e aí esta o problema... Quando tento enviar de qualquer forma os dados pelo arduino+sim900 (AT+HTTPDATA,AT+CIPSEND ou algum outro), simplesmente chegam informações "vazias" para mim no site e consequentemente são adicionados valores "vazios" no Banco de dados como na imagem abaixo:

[image: Bando de Dados MySQL]
Código atual da página PHP de ADD.php no Banco de Dados:

```
include("connect.php");

$link=Connection();

$Bateria=$_POST["Bateria"];
$Odometro=$_POST["Odometro"];
$Consumo=$_POST["Consumo"];
$Carro_Padrao=$_POST["Carro_Padrao"];

$query = "INSERT INTO `u984057597_app`.`SMS_Recebidos`(`timeStamp`,`Bateria`,`Odometro`,`Consumo`,`Carro_Padrao`) VALUES (DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 HOUR),'".$Bateria."','".$Odometro."','".$Consumo."','".$Carro_Padrao."')"; 

mysql_query($query,$link);
mysql_close($link);
```

Alguém já teve este mesmo problema e conseguiu solucionar?,
é necessário algum comando a mais na pagina de add.php? (ela recebe os dados do arduino)

Agradeço a todos desde já!

Comment: Thiago, seja bem-vindo. Edite sua pergunta e adicione o código, sem a utilização de imagem pois isso dificulta a verificação dele. Recomendo que faça uma leitura do [Tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Obrigado @MarcelodeAndrade, já editei o mesmo e estou verificando o Tour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problema resolvido!

A configuração que havia inserido na pergunta estava tudo OK e não demandou modificações (pagina ADD.php).

Para resolver o problema de captura (método POST no site) tive de efetuar algumas modificações na biblioteca padrão do módulo SIM900 do fornecedor TinySine, sendo elas:

```
1- Modificar a linha 37 do arquivo GSM.cpp para o BaudRate 4800 (antigo era 9600).

2- Modificar a linha 4 do arquivo HWSerial.cpp para o BaudRate 4800(antigo era 9600).

3- Adicionar as seguintes sintaxes na programação do arduino:
```

ORIGINAL

```
numdata=inet.httpPOST("site", 80, "/arduino/add.php", "variavel=valor&variavel2=valor2",msg, 50);
```

MODIFICADA

```
char temp_string[64];
char msg[100];
int numdata;
String valor = "Bateria=13.2V&Odometro=10250Km&Consumo=12.3Km/L&Carro_Padrao=A4";
valor.toCharArray(temp_string, 64);
numdata = inet.httpPOST("site", 80, "/arduino/add.php", temp_string, msg, 50);
delay(5000);
```

Nesta ultima etapa tive que fazer uma especie de concatenação com conversão de variáveis e somente desta forma consegui resolver o meu problema em questão.

Obrigado a ajuda de todos!

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt, como sua resposta resolveu o seu próprio problema, você poderá marca-la como resposta aceita em 2 dias, lembre-se disso :) Nesse tempo você pode fazer um (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)[Tour] pelo site, e explorar tudo o que o SOpt tem de bom.

Answer (score 0):

De:

```
$variavel1=$_GET["variavel1"];
$variavel2=$_GET["variavel2"];
$variavel3=$_GET["variavel3"];
$variavel4=$_GET["variavel4"];
```

Para:

```
$variavel1=$_POST["variavel1"];
$variavel2=$_POST["variavel2"];
$variavel3=$_POST["variavel3"];
$variavel4=$_POST["variavel4"];
```

Lembre-se também de alterar o método no formulário: `method=post`.

Comment: Obrigado pela pronta resposta, esta modificação (POST) já havia feito acabei colocando a imagem antiga do código... já o método formulário seria para eu utilizar na pagina que estou enviando correto? A pagina que postei ali é a pagina que "recebe" o dado então acho que não se aplica neste caso... @LipESprY

Comment: Na página do formulado, vc deve colocar o method como POST e na página que trata os dados, usa-se $_POST['var'].

Comment: Seu comentário acabou me ajudando a achar a solução, tive que pesquisar em como o arduino fazia esse "formulado", e acabei encontrando alguns defeitos na biblioteca padrão do fabricante e acabei tendo de efetuar algumas modificações! Respondi com a solução ali acima para que qualquer pessoa que necessite futuramente de um auxilio tenha este outro caminho que encontrei, obrigado!.. @LipESprY